# SQL return displaying incorrectly

Tags: sql, text

I have a table which displays data from a SQL table onto my site, the issue I am having is depending on the alpha data being displayed the placement of the word moves, i.e. when displaying the word GOOD it displays in the position I want but when it displays the word FAIR it then shift to the left.

Any advice on how to stop this from happening ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Please read that link and make sure that the code you post in your question is minimal (only bare minimum of code necessary to reproduce), complete (all of the code necessary to reproduce) and verifiable (we can reproduce the issue using only the code in your question). JsFiddle links don't count as an MCVE. Without an MCVE in your question, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a while loop to get results from your data table,you can use php to create a new element for displaying your data like so:

```
$open = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($open)) {
    $DataName = $row['NameOfData'] 
    echo "<h3>$DataName</h3>"}
```

Replace `NameOfData` with the row you're trying to get. Look up "PHP Mysql row outputting" for more information

Comment: THis *might* work ***IF*** the OP is really using PHP - but that's not mentioned anywhere in the question body or the tags. ....

Comment: Actually it _would_ work, and he did not mention if he was using PHP, I was just guessing because he did not specify .....

Comment: C# is not for websites, he clearly states that he is trying to display the results on his website, in his post .........

Comment: So what is C# with ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC for then ?!?!??!?!?

Comment: Thanks Jacob, much appreciated will try that out.  @ Marc_s - you got a bad attitude buddy, we all trying to learn here and snarking comments are not needed.